# Is it possible to control the legend key size when using ggdag?

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am drawing DAGs in R using `ggdag` and I would like to change the size of the legend key without changing the size of the DAG nodes.

The `theme()` argument `legend.key.size` appears to control the size of an invisible box around the legend key, but doesn't affect the actual key size, as illustrated by the code below.

```
ggdag::confounder_triangle() %>% 
  ggdag::node_status() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y, color = status)) + 
  geom_dag_point() +
  theme(legend.key.size = grid::unit(3, 'cm'))
```

The key size appears to respond to the `size` argument in `geom_dag_point()`, as illustrated with this code:

```
ggdag::confounder_triangle() %>% 
  ggdag::node_status() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y, color = status)) + 
  geom_dag_point(size = 4)
```

Is it possible to change the key size without changing the node size?

Comment: Can you share a the output of `confoudner_triangle` so that we can run that code and help you to solve this problem?!

Comment: Sorry, `confounder_triangle` is a function from `ggdag`. I've edited the question to clarify. Hopefully that is reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `size` of the `color` with the `guide_legend` by the same `override.aes` argument in your `guides`. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggdag)
library(ggplot2)
ggdag::confounder_triangle() %>% 
  ggdag::node_status() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y, color = status)) + 
  ggdag::geom_dag_point() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>